# MySQL multi-layer filtering based on criteria from one column

Tags: mysql

In my table I've got a list of names, email addresses and a column called referrer. A users name and email is entered multiple times into the table for a contest. The referrer column tells me how the contestant heard about the contest.

How do I get a recordset of contestants that shows if the referrer is `web` and/or `email` but only choose one record for each? For example, a contestant could be entered 10 times under `email` and 100 times under `web`. What I'm trying to do is get just a single instance of each record.

This is my current query:

```
select * from table_contestants 
where referrer IN ('email', 'web') GROUP BY email order by referrer;
```

Of course, when I use `GROUP BY` it only gives me one instance of the record regardless of whether it's found to have `email` or `web`.

Removing the `GROUP BY` will give me all the instances, which is a lot...

How do I write the query to give me one record of each contestant that has both `email` and `web`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is various solution depending on your need:

If you just need distinct (name, email) pairs regardless of referer, use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, email FROM tbl 
WHERE referer IN ("email", "web");
```

---

If you need distinct (name, email, referrer) tuple, the same solution applies:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, email, referer FROM tbl 
WHERE referer IN ("email", "web");
```

---

As an extension to SQL, MySQL allow in the `SELECT` clause reference to non-aggregate column not referenced in the `GROUP BY` clause. In that case, the value of the non-aggregate column is undetermined (understand: "is one of the values of the group" and "the result is un-reproductible").

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

So if you need distinct (name, email) pairs and *one* origin without preference, the following query will work *with MySQL*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, email, referer FROM tbl
WHERE referer IN ("email", "web")
GROUP BY name, email;
```

---

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85292/5 for a comparison;

Answer (score 0):

Just use DISTINCT...

```
select distinct(referrer) as user from table_contestants 
where referrer IN ('email', 'web') GROUP BY email order by referrer;
```

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of a GROUP BY clause is simply inappropriate.

Comment: @Strawberry in "plain SQL standard" you are right: non-aggregate column not referenced in the group by clause are not allowed in the select clause. But MySQL explicitly accept that as an extension. The value in one of the value in the group, at the server discretion.